How do I apply only security updates in terminal?
My server uses the ubuntu operating system. After a while, I saw a lot of update notifications. But I only want to update the security part, so how do I use the command?

Why not apply all upgrades? sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and comment non-security repositories with #:
Example: from deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble main restricted to # deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble main restricted
Then run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.
P.S: This is generally a terrible practice and may cause potential dependency issues (make sure to read @muru's comment on this answer, thus after the operation DO REVERT the sources.list file to normal.

As given, this is terrible advice. Do not comment out the base noble repository.

@muru This is generally a bad practice, I agree, only in certain conditions where this is the only way it's suggested (like when you're out of storage and want to temporarily just upgrade security packages and not a full upgrade)

The base repository isn't getting updates, though. It gets frozen on release and updates are provided via -security/-updates. What you will do is suddenly cause apt to think a bunch of packages vanished from the repositories, potentially messing up dependency management for no good reason.
